# Refresh Table of contents page numbering on open

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I have a word document with table of contents.
I manipulate it externally (with C#) and then wish to view it.
the table of contents has to be refreshed manually (Right click -> ...).
Is it possible to define auto refresh, similar to Pivot table in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric White has posted a series of screencasts on this issue.

See it at [tables-of-contents-in-open-xml-wordprocessingml-documents](http://ericwhite.com/blog/2011/08/08/new-screen-cast-series-on-tables-of-contents-in-open-xml-wordprocessingml-documents/)